# Using SASS placeholder for muti-colored menu

Tags: css, sass

I have a menu with 4 items.  Each of the 4 items are to be colored similarly and behave the same on hover, except that the BASE COLOR of each is supposed to be different.

I thought I could do this in SASS, so I created a mixin:

```
@mixin boxmenuitem($color:#D49A15) {
background-color: lighten($color, 20%);;
@include background-image(linear-gradient($color, darken($color, 10%)));
&:hover {
    background-image: none;
    li {
        background-image: none;
        &:hover {
            background-color: darken($color, 10%) ;
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

And I apply it as such (all irrelevant menu code removed):

```
.menu-class {
ul {
    li {
        @include boxmenuitem;
        &:last-child {
            @include boxmenuitem(#ff0000);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

However, this also affects every SUBMENU li:last-child.

Can I re-arrange this in such a way to apply it correctly?

I was looking for something I could do like:

```
li {
   @include boxmenuitem;
   &:nth-child(1) {
       @include boxmenuitem(blue);
   }
   &:nth-child(2) {
       @include boxmenuitem(green);
   }
   ...etc...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use the direct child selector of CSS `>`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I would up doing this:

```
@mixin boxmenuitem($color:#D49A15, $image:"bg-prac-home-crim.jpg") {
   @include background-image(linear-gradient($color, darken($color, 10%)));
   @include box-shadow(2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: lighten($color,10%) darken($color,20%) darken($color,20%) lighten($color, 10%);
   .home & { // only home page has an image
    @include background-image(
        url("assets/images/"+$image),
        linear-gradient($color, darken($color, 10%)));  
    background-position: center 35px, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
    height: 150px;
    &:hover {
        @include background-image(
            url("assets/images/bg-prac-home-crim.jpg"),
            linear-gradient(lighten($color, 10%), darken($color, 1%)));
    }
    li {
        &:hover {
            background-color: darken($color, 10%) ;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And then applying this to only direct descendants:

```
.second-menu-class {
@include clearfix;
// first level LI
>ul>li {
    &:first-child { 
                @include boxmenuitem;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
        @include boxmenuitem(#67A2A6, "bg-prac-home-empl.jpg");
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
        @include boxmenuitem(#4D4D4D, "bg-prac-home-real.jpg");
    }
    &:last-child {
        @include boxmenuitem(#843C3F, "bg-prac-home-family.jpg");
    }
 }
```